# Warum ist Leben Singular: "Es gibt Menschen, die setzen ihr Leben aufs Spiel, um einen Berggipfel zu bezwingen."

Tags: word-usage

Es gibt Menschen (Plural)- aber ihr Leben(Singular) wird gesetzt von Menschen.

*Die Unendliche Geschichte*, Kapitel eins:

> Es gibt Menschen, die setzen ihr Leben aufs Spiel, um einen Berggipfel
>   zu bezwingen.

---

Hypothese: In einigen Sprachen, wenn eine Gruppe von Menschen etwas individuell für sich selbst tut, ist die untergeordnete Handlung im Singular. Ist das hier der Fall?

Comment: Weil jeder Mensch (vermutlich) nur ein Leben hat?

Comment: @IQV ok. Ist das der Grund? Es gibt zu nicht mehr als das?

Comment: Ja, diese subtile Art der Kongruenz ist im wesentlichen willkürlich geregelt. Das Deutsche verwendet den Singular, das Englische den Plural: "Three brave men gave their live*s*." Im französischen ist es wiederum der Singular, usw.

Comment: Das Englische kennt eine Konstruktion, die sich "possessiver Plural" nennt. Das Deutsche kennt die nicht, bzw. die Regel, dass "Eigentümer" und "Eigentum" einander streng im Numerus folgen müssen, ist im Deutschen bei weitem weniger streng .

Comment: So kann man sie von Computerspielern unterscheiden, die 2-3 Leben aufs Spiel setzen, um den nächsten Level zu erreichen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Entgegen meiner vorherigen Antwort scheint das Folgende nicht möglich zu sein:

> Es gibt Menschen, die setzen *ihre* Leben aufs Spiel, ...

Zwar habe ich noch immer keine grammatikalische Regel dazu gefunden, jedoch wurde diese Formulierung in der gesammelten deutschen Literatur (Quelle: www.dwds.de) bisher nicht verwendet, mit einer Ausnahme:

> Diesen Gedankengang konnte man schon im Sophisten angedeutet finden; daß dem All Vernunft, Seele, Bewußtsein nicht fehlen könne, hieß schon dort nichts andres als daß die allseitige Durchdringung der Ideen, ihre wechselseitige und wechselnde Bezüglichkeit, in der alles Werden und konkrete Sein logisch beruht, wirklich stattfindet und kraft ihrer Leben, Seele und Erkenntnis möglich und wirklich ist.

Ohne hier nun zu philosophisch zu werden lässt sich der Unterschied doch erkennen.
In dem vorliegenden Text werden alle Leben dem *All* als Besitz zugeschrieben. Im Gegensatz zum Menschen, dem immer nur sein eigenes, einzelnes Leben gehört, gehört jenem All also eine Menge von Leben.

Die einzig sinnvolle Regel, die sich daraus ableiten lässt und mit allen von mir spontan geprüften anderen Beispielen übereinstimmt, wäre:

> Ist jedem *[Subjekt]* genau ein *[Objekt]* zugeordnet, so verwendet man das Possessivpronomen im *Singular*. 
>   Sind jedem *[Subjekt]* mehrere *[Objekt]* zugeordnet, so verwendet man das Possessivpronomen im *Plural*.

Vielen Dank an die Kommentare, die mich zu weiteren Recherchen angeregt haben.

Comment: Kannst Du die Behauptung der Gemeinsamkeit irgendwie belegen?

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt nein. Ich habe etwas recherchiert, aber das Thema in der Literatur bisher nicht gefunden. Ich werde versuchen einen Beleg nachzuliefern.

Comment: Ich finde "Es gibt Menschen, die setzen ihre Leben aufs Spiel" eine recht unnatürliche Form des Ausdrucks. Eigentlich kann ich mir nicht vorstellen, dass außerhalb einer Diskussion wie eben dieser hier irgend jemand dies sagen würde.

Comment: Ich habe meine Antwort geändert